# Xcode app is stuck in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I've just recently begun learning to use Xcode and Objective-C. As usual, I decided to begin by learning how to create a Hello, World app.
For some reason, even though I'm designing everything for portrait mode, it keeps showing landscape mode in the simulator and on my iPad 2.
[image: In Xcode]
In Xcode
[image: In the simulator an on the iPad]
In the simulator an on the iPad

Here is the code of the view controller, if that helps at all.

```
#import "LCViewController.h"

@interface LCViewController ()

@end

@implementation LCViewController
@synthesize helloButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setHelloButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Hello!"
                                                    message:@"Hello, world!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    [helloButton setTitle:@"I was clicked!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

EDIT: With Red background
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give that viewcontroller a background color in viewDidLoad `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` and upload the screenshot again? It would be easier to spot the/a problem.

Comment: Also, you seem to be editing the iPhone sized window ... you will have to use an iPad storyboard/window to get proper results.

Comment: Added a red background.

How does one change the storyboard window? I apologize. I'm very new to this. Previously I've only done command line programs.

Comment: Thanks, it more clear now. So it scales nicely, but it starts in landscape? U might have set the "Initial interface orientation" in your `AppName-Info.plist` file to portrait. You can remove that row if you want it to launch in the current phone orientation (in simulator usually portrait).

Comment: Usually when you create an app you get asked if it should be iPhone, iPad or Universal. If you are new to all this just start with iPhone and leave the iPad and universal versions for now. Maybe have a look at these lectures from stanford in iTunesU? It's free and they start from the ground up. helped me a lot. [itunes-u-link](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=473757255)

Comment: Ah, thanks! Such a simple problem!
That helped!

Comment: There is also a ruler thingy in the top right of interface builder. Select the button and then play around with the alignment settings. If you got the new XCode, have a look at the developer videos from apple about Constrains.

Answer (score 1):

Supported orientations was accidentally set to landscape. 
Set orientation on the project main screen in the Supported Orientations section or in the plist file.

Answer (score 0):

See in the attributes inspector what voice is selected for "mode".

Comment: Looks like it says 'Scale to Fit'.